# Calling methods in order but excluding methods of one parent class

Tags: python

**Consider following setup**:

A decorator that keeps track of the functions which have been called in a class:

```
def called_methods(func):
    def inner(self):
        func(self)
        self.called.append(func)
    return inner
```

Three classes with each two type of methods. Each print a unique statement:

```
class ClassOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.called = list()

    @called_methods
    def method_one_a(self):
        print("method one, a")

    @called_methods
    def method_one_b(self):
        print("method one, b")


class ClassTwo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.called = list()

    @called_methods
    def method_two_a(self):
        print("method two, a")

    @called_methods
    def method_two_b(self):
        print("method two, b")


class ClassThree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.called = list()

    @called_methods
    def method_three_a(self):
        print("method three, a")

    @called_methods
    def method_three_b(self):
        print("method three, b")
```

A class which inherit from the three other classes, and can call the methods in the order they have been called:

```
class MainClass(ClassOne, ClassTwo, ClassThree):
        def call_functions_in_order(self):
            for function in self.called:
                function(self)
```

**An example:** Some methods have been called in an arbitrary order:

```
test = MainClass()
test.method_one_a()
test.method_two_b()
test.method_one_b()
test.method_three_a()
test.method_two_a()
test.method_three_b()
```

Which results in the following output:

```
method one, a
method two, b
method one, b
method three, a
method two, a
method three, b
```

and `test.call_functions_in_order()` will again give the same output.

***The goal:***

I would like to be able to specify if the methods of one of the parent classes should not be called. So the `call_functions_in_order` method has an "exclude" parameter, and the previous example would output:

```
test.call_functions_in_order(exclude='ClassOne')
method two, b
method three, a
method two, a
method three, b
```

Anyone has a good idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Something like `if not function.__qualname__.startswith(f'{exclude}.'):` before calling `function(self)`?

Comment: If one of the methods should not be called, then your class hierarchy isn't defined correctly.

Comment: @chepner That might be, but that was not the question..

Comment: Are you sure you are asking [the right question](https://xyproblem.info) in the first place?

Comment: Pretty sure, but thank you for asking